# SQL Server Express & sqlcmd : could not find stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-express, sqlcmd

I inherited a database that lives in a SQL Server Express instance and realized it wasn't getting backed up. Since it is SQL Server Express and there isn't a SQL Server Agent, I found this article describing how to automate backups.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se

The backup script works correctly and I can run the stored procedure successfully from SQL Server Management Studio to create the backups. My trouble starts at Step B, using `sqlcmd`.

No matter what I do, it just errors saying

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_backupDatabases'

[image]

The stored procedure exists in the master DB:

[image]

Also, I tested running the command using one of the system stored procedures, and it executes those fine as well. It just can't seem to find this custom stored procedure I created.

I've also run this command:

```
select * from information_schema.routines
```

and my stored procedure is found in one of the records.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Wild guess `USE master` and use `EXEC master.dbo.sp_backupDatabases ...` without `[]`. Maybe there is a space in name or you are connecting to different instance.

Comment: I've tried both of those before, with [], without, and pretty much every version of the name you could imagine.  Funny thing is, is I can execute this command completely fine:  sqlcmd -S .\SQL2008R2 -E -Q "EXEC [sys].[sp_datatype_info]"  Without any bells or whistles and it finds the SP successfully.  I thought maybe it's working off of a cached table somewhere and needs refreshed but not sure how to do that if that is a thing.

Comment: So most likely it is a permission issue. Are you using the same user to connect via SSMS/sqlcmd?

Comment: Still no dice, I have been running the command prompt as administrator, but to be sure I ran it as the user I am running in SSMS and I get the same message.

Comment: Last idea: `EXEC sp_backupDatabases` without schema and DB

Comment: Hell yeah, this worked without the DB and instance name:  sqlcmd -E -Q "EXEC sp_backupDatabases @backupLocation='F:\SQLBackups\',@backupType='F'"   I have no idea why...but thanks!   put in an answer and I can uptick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with name resolution. I would try to skip database/schema name i.e:

```
EXEC sp_backupDatabases ...
```